# Passing objects to be used by partials inside a layout

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sails.js, ejs

I have a page layout with a sidebar and a main content. Both are dynamic according to the user profile.

```
<html>
  <body>

    <%- partial('partials/sidebar')%>

    <html with <% ejs code %> for body>

  </body>
</html>
```

Sails view should be:

```
res.view( {mydata} );
```

How can I pass data to the partials so it can be dynamically rendered instead of static?

Example:

controller:

```
res.view( {mainContent:{mainContentJson}, sidebar:{sidebarJson} );
```

layout.ejs:

```
<html>
  <body>

    <%- partial('partials/sidebar', sidebar)%>

    <html with ejs code for body>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Partials accept arguments to be passed, and they are rendered before being inserted into the calling layout.

controller:

```
res.view( {
         layout:<yourCustomLayoutIfNeeded>, 
         mainContent: <mainContentObject>, 
         partialContent: <partialContentObject>
        });
```

yourCustomLayoutIfNeeded:

```
<%- partial(<pathToPartial>, partialContent) %>
<mainContent>
```